# How to determinate an object class with Class<?> clazz

Tags: java, class, generics

How can I determinate if entity and request are same type class of clazz
(Example: `if(entity.equals(clazz) && request.equals(clazz))` but not work.
(In this case, i assigned `ContattoCliente.class` to `clazz` so that if is `true` (`if (clazz == ContattoCliente.class)`)

Language Java version 11.

```
private Object convertMapMergedToEntity(Object entity, Object request, Class<?> clazz) {
        List<Object> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        Object clienteMerged = new Object();
        ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder().addModule(new JavaTimeModule()).build();
        if (clazz == ContattoCliente.class) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((List<Object>) request).size(); i++) {
                Object contattoMerged = new Object();
                LinkedHashMap<Object, Object> entityMap = mapper.convertValue(((List<Object>) entity).get(i),
                        LinkedHashMap.class);
                LinkedHashMap<Object, Object> requestMap = mapper.convertValue(((List<Object>) request).get(i),
                        LinkedHashMap.class);

                contattoMerged = mapDifferenceMerged2(entityMap, requestMap, clazz);
                resultList.add(contattoMerged);
            }
            return resultList;
        } else if (clazz == Cliente.class) {
            LinkedHashMap<Object, Object> entityMap = mapper.convertValue(entity, LinkedHashMap.class);
            LinkedHashMap<Object, Object> requestMap = mapper.convertValue(request, LinkedHashMap.class);
            clienteMerged = mapDifferenceMerged2(entityMap, requestMap, clazz);
        }

        return clienteMerged;
    }


The problem is that if i compare them with Getclass () the condition will always be false, I have also tried everything that is after Dot Getclass ()
        System.out.println("entity  ->" + entity.getClass());
        System.out.println("request  -> " + request.getClass());
        System.out.println("clazz  ->" + clazz.getSimpleName());

Output:
entity -> class org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag
request -> class java.util.LinkedList
clazz -> ContattoCliente
```

Comment: Do you want to check whether the class *exactly* matches, or whether it's compatible (i.e. a subclass)? Are there generics involved, or are these concrete, runtime classes?

Comment: While `entity instanceof clazz` does not work, `clazz.isAssignableFrom(entity.getClass())` at least compiles

Comment: I need to check if entity and request are of the same clazz type. When I call this method I pass the entity retrieved from the db, the request from the front end and clazz.
as:
listContatti = (List <ContattoCliente>) convertMapMergedToEntity (entity.getContattiCliente (),
requestConverted.getContattiCliente (), ContattoCliente.class);
entity.setContattiCliente (listContatti);
Customer customerAssembled = (Customer) convertMapMergedToEntity (entity, requestConverted, Customer.class);  Beacause i build convertMapMergedToEntity like a common method to use for different entity

Comment: @XtremeBaumer `Object.equals(Object)` method returns a `boolean`. It will be then auto boxed to a `Boolean` object and compared with a `Class` object in your snippet, which is meaningless and always returns `false`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is what you expected, but if you what to check whether `entity` and `request` are *compatible* with `clazz`, you can use [`Class.isInstance(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-), that's to say `clazz.isInstance(entity) && clazz.isInstance(request)`.

Comment: Yes, i would like to check if that object are compatible with clazz, but i try your code (clazz.isInstance(entity) && clazz.isInstance(request)) but not work

Comment: @Cheps Are `entity` and `request` generic class objects? I see you cast them to `List<Object>` in your code. You cannot check whether two objects are of the same generic type (that means the classes of `ArrayList<String>` `ArrayList<Object>` are the same), as [generic parameters are erased](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html) at runtime in Java.

Comment: @Cheps but you can implement a method like `<T> process(Collection<T>, Collection<? extends T>)` to achieve that purpose.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the method you're looking is [`isAssignableFrom`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)). This method checks that a class is equal to, or subclass from the other.

So your code should look like this

```java
if (ContattoCliente.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
```

Answer (score -1):

I understood that you need to check whether `entity` and `request` are instances of the same class, and that you added the third parameter `clazz` because you previous attempts to check the "type equality" failed.

What about this:

```java
if( nonNull( entity ) && nonNull( request ) && entity.getClass().equals( request.getClass() ) )
{
  …   
}
```

If the class for the arguments has to be that one specified by `clazz`, think about this construct:

```java
private <T> Object convertMapMergedToEntity( T entity, T request, Class<T> clazz) 
{
  …
}
```

Here enforces the compiler that `entity` and `request` are of the type `T` that is specified by the `clazz` parameter; it does not require a runtime check any more.

If you want to have the runtime check by any means, try this (but add `null` checks for at least `entity` and `request`):

```java
if( entity.getClass().equals( request.getClass() && entity.getClass().equals( clazz ) ) )
{
  …   
}
```